# currentBackStackEntry arguments is null when launching the app

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

In a compose app I'm trying to update the arguments of the currentBackStackEntry. It's just a side project.
I do:

```
navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.putParcelable(
    "comic",
    selectedComic
)
```

I know I should probably use room to persist the value and only pass the id and/or use other compose navigation libs (as [compose destinations](https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations) or [appyx](https://github.com/bumble-tech/appyx)) instead of passing parcelables this way but I want to keep it simple with compose navigation and without having it serialised in the url.

The problem is that the code doesn't always work and I don't understand why, when it loads the first time as first destination `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments` is `null` so the code doesn't work. After navigating to any other composable if I go back to this one and that same code is executed arguments is not null and that code seems to always work.

Any ideas of something I could do so that the arguments are not empty the first time the app is run? I would also really want to understand why this is happening. I've being trying to find out what's happening for several days before asking in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the code doesn't always work and I don't understand why, when it loads the first time as first destination navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments is null so the code doesn't work.

The [documentation for that method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#getCurrentBackStackEntry()) states (emphasis mine):

> the topmost entry on the back stack **or null if the back stack is empty**

When "it loads the first time as first destination" it's expected that there is no backstack, by definition, so this is completely expected.

Furthermore, the documenttion for [currentBackStackEntry.arguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavBackStackEntry#getArguments()) states:

> Note that the arguments of a NavBackStackEntry are immutable and defined when you navigate() to the destination - changes you make to this Bundle will not be reflected in future calls to this property.

So it would seem that attempting to put stuff in that `Bundle` is incorrect anyway.

> Any ideas of something I could do so that the arguments are not empty the first time the app is run?

I've not used the Nav library myself, but just from reading the docs, maybe [currentDestination](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#getCurrentDestination()).[arguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDestination#getArguments()) is what you want instead?

Answer (score -2):

You can use my own implementation for jetpack compose navigation:
https://github.com/usmonie/compose_navigation_with_parcelable_arguments

Use rememberNavExtrasController for creating controller, NavExtrasHost and com.usmonie.compose.navigation.composable for passing bundle with arguments.